# sql where clause condition not working as expected.need only specific tag records

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This my request, I have to get customer report that should include CUST_ID(primary key),PHONE_NUM(mandatory),EMAIL(optional),ATTRIBUTE_VALUE(mandatory) BY joining 3 tables.
The report should consist of the only registered customers who has ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'REG' and anything.
but the ATTRIBUTE_VALUE should not have 'UNREG'and 'GUEST';

table name : **CST_CUST_ATTRIBUTES**

| cust_id | attribute_value |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

table name : **CST_CUST_PHONE**

| cust_id | PHONE_NUM |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

table name : **CST_EMAIL**

| cust_id | EMAIL_ADDR |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Below is my query. The joins parts are fine but where clause conditioning is not working as expected. I validated the records in a random.'UNREG' and 'GUEST' ATTRIBUTE_VALUE customers also gets included in the record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   A.CUST_ID,
   B.PHONE_NUM,
   C.EMAIL_ADDR,
   A.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE 
FROM
   CST_CUST_ATTRIBUTES A 
   INNER JOIN
      CST_CUST_PHONE B 
      ON A.CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID 
   LEFT JOIN
      CST_EMAIL C 
      ON B.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID 
WHERE
   A.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'REG' 
   and A.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE not in 
   (
      'UNREG',
      'GUEST'
   )
```

iam using oracle pl/sql developer 12.kindly need help in the expected where condition.

Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: So, a cust_id can have more than one attribute? If so, then [where a.value = reg and a.cust_id not in (select cust_id from table where value in (unreg, guest)]. But it really depends on your data and how it looks, and what exactly you want.

Comment: provided a sample data and the expected result. Why are you making left join by cust_id again the email table ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez please give solution for the where condition .attribute_value is from cst_cust_attribute table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `where` clause should be something like this:

```
where a.attribute_value = 'REG'
  and not exists (select null
                  from cst_cust_attributes x
                  where x.cust_id = a.cust_id
                    and x.attribute_value in ('UNREG', 'GUEST')
                 )
```

---

Though, it is quite difficult to test as sample data you posted is rather *poor*. "row"? Where are "REG" and "GUEST"?

Comment: Thank you so much.but customer duplicate mobile numbers are coming.is there any fix?

Comment: No idea, sorry. As I said, sample data is *bad*. I suggest you edit the original question you posted and provide data that illustrates the problem; then we might be able to assist further.

Comment: can u please explain ? select null..... part

Comment: Could've been *anything*; its (subquerie's) role is just to make sure it returns *something*, it doesn't matter what it is - NULL is as good as 1, 'X', some column ...

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity might be an issue here. You may give a try to -

```
AND UPPER(A.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE) NOT IN ('UNREG', 'GUEST');
```